# Using cookies in ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm trying to build a website that enables users to vote for things. The website works, but a user can vote multiple times. How can I prevent that?

I read online that I can use cookies. But I don't know how to implement them in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

Can you tell me how to use cookies for preventing multiple voting in ASP.NET MVC 5?

A small code snippet for starting would be great.

Comment: Doing so won't help much, cookies can easily be cleared by anyone.

Comment: @PeterB using cookies will solve my problem.

Comment: If your problem is a homework assignment, then yes. Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: @PeterB no it's not a homework assignment.

Comment: Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Using cookies will not be a good idea for your scenario. consider storing the userid and his vote cast information in database instead

Comment: You might find some ideas (but I don't know if they are better) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572723/stopping-users-voting-multiple-times-on-a-website

Comment: Using cookies might not be the best idea. Users can delete the cookies. 
Having them make a profile, use an emailadres, limits the amount of votes.
Maybe look at his IP adress (altough...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<script>

    if (Cookies.get("HasAnswered") == 1) {
        $("#spn_Answered").text("Answered");
    }


    $("#btn_Answer").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (Cookies.get("HasAnswered") == 1)
            alert("You have already answered the question");
        else {
            Cookies.set("HasAnswered", 1);
            $("#spn_Answered").text("Answered");
            alert("Congrats you have answered");
        }
    });

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Cookie</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.0/js.cookie.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Answer Now" id="btn_Answer" />
    <span id="spn_Answered"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**1**.
 You can use some sort of logic and place that in a cookie. Like

If user answered then mark the cookie value to 1 else make it 0.

Ex.   Cookies.set('**IsReplied**', 1);

**2**.
You can use this nice JS library.
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

It provides a good documentation through which you can apply the cookies easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be great if you could write an example. Thanks.

Comment: It is not working in stack overflow envoirement. There may be somthing missing. But the code is correct. copy and paste the code on your machine and it should work.